# Is it permitted to desecrate a flag containing the shahada?

Tags: shahada

I wouldn't desecrate a shahada for the sake of desecrating a shahada. But if a flag contained a shahada (for example Saudi Arabia), would it be forbidden by Islam to desecrate that flag?

Comment: I indeed approve these kinds of questions as you ask which can be so constructive for the readers... / God Bless You.

Comment: I think that a primary factor for an answer is; what is the intention of desecrating the flag which is containing the shahada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inquired about a nice inquiry. Yeah, seemingly it has the ruling of Allah names (and his Rasul (Apostle)), then it could be compared with desecrate a paper which consists of Allah names. consequently we ought not to desecrate it even if we do not its country or brand.